# Visual Studio 2017 не видит инклюды

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

**Visual Studio 2017** не видит заголовочные файлы `Windows.h`, `WinSock2.h`, `WS2tcpip.h`.
Какие версии **Visual C++** необходимо установить и что надо сделать в самой Visual Studio, чтобы иметь возможность пользоваться всем вышеупомянутым?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При установке Visual Studio 2017 вы что говорили? Что просили установить? От типа Windows SDK не отказались случаем? Я бы просто заново запустил инсталлятор и указал необходимые опции - обратите внимание на всякие SDK на копии экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.